# [r]: Interpreting results of a glmer, retransforming estimates

Tags: r, glm

EDIT:
I am currently writing my master thesis on the effect of a certain insecticide on bumble bee colonies. I was for example checking if damaged/diseased appearing bees were more prevalent in colonies that were exposed to the insecticide compared to the control.

The study design is hierarchical. 16 fields were paired according to landscape characteristics. In each pair one field was randomly assigned to be treated with the insecticide, while the other is the control field. In each field there are 2 boxes and in each box are 2 bumble bee hives. From each hive I have up to ten pupae per sex.

This is how my data looks like:

```
    structure(list(pair = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L
), .Label = c("P01", "P02", "P03", "P04", "P05", "P10", "P11", 
"P12"), class = "factor"), field = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), .Label = c("VR02", "VR03", 
"VR04", "VR05", "VR06", "VR07", "VR09", "VR12", "VR13", "VR14", 
"VR16", "VR17", "VR18", "VR20", "VR21", "VR23"), class = "factor"), 
    treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Clothianidin", "Control"), class = "factor"), 
    box.nested = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 23, 23, 23, 
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
    19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
    26, 26, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
    31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
    32, 32, 32, 32, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 18, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
    22, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 30, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
    30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30), hive.nested = c(21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
    23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 45L, 45L, 
    45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 48L, 
    48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
    38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 
    49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 
    26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 
    61L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 
    64L, 64L, 64L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 36L, 
    36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
    34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 41L, 41L, 
    41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 
    43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
    17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
    19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
    54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 
    56L, 56L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
    57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 
    59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L), stage = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "factor"), condition = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("d", 
    "h"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("f", "m", "q"
    ), class = "factor"), diseased = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("pair", 
"field", "treatment", "box.nested", "hive.nested", "stage", "condition", 
"sex", "diseased"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(5L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 45L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 58L, 60L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 72L, 73L, 
74L, 77L, 83L, 85L, 87L, 90L, 92L, 95L, 97L, 100L, 104L, 108L, 
115L, 117L, 123L, 125L, 133L, 134L, 137L, 144L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 
158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 166L, 169L, 170L, 172L, 
175L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 184L, 185L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 199L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
211L, 212L, 213L, 215L, 217L, 221L, 222L, 224L, 226L, 230L, 244L, 
247L, 255L, 258L, 262L, 271L, 272L, 274L, 280L, 281L, 284L, 285L, 
288L, 289L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 299L, 300L, 305L, 308L, 309L, 312L, 
314L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 
356L, 359L, 362L, 364L, 366L, 375L, 378L, 381L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 
391L, 392L, 393L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 412L, 
417L, 418L, 420L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L, 431L, 
432L, 433L, 435L, 436L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 
446L, 447L, 450L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 456L, 458L, 459L, 461L, 462L, 
465L, 466L, 468L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 
483L, 484L, 485L, 486L, 487L, 490L, 491L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 500L, 
501L, 508L, 518L, 519L, 521L, 522L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 
529L, 530L, 531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 535L, 538L, 540L, 542L, 543L, 
544L, 548L, 549L, 551L, 552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 559L, 
560L, 563L, 568L, 569L, 571L, 572L, 576L, 577L, 578L, 579L, 580L, 
581L, 582L, 583L, 584L, 585L, 587L, 588L, 590L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 
600L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 608L, 609L, 616L, 618L, 620L, 
622L, 626L, 628L, 631L, 632L, 635L, 636L, 638L, 639L, 641L, 646L, 
647L, 651L, 652L, 653L, 654L, 655L, 656L, 658L, 659L, 660L, 661L, 
663L, 666L, 667L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 673L, 675L, 676L, 678L, 679L, 
680L, 681L, 682L, 684L, 685L, 686L, 687L, 688L, 689L, 690L))
```

I have run binomial glmer models from the lme4 package to test whether the presence of disease/damage signs in bumble bee colonies is affected by the insecticide.

```
damage.prev <- glmer(diseased ~ treatment + sex + stage
                 + (1|pair/field/box.nested/hive.nested)
                 ,data=df.cocoons.white, 
                 family=binomial)
```

I have been trying to get estimates and confidence intervals. Thanks to @Benjamin
I got a little closer to the solution, but the estimates sill seem too high.

That's how I tried to get a data.frame of CIs and estimates:

```
fixed <- fixef(damage.prev)
wald <-confint(damage.prev,method="Wald") 

estCloth.damage.ratio <- exp(fixed[1])
estCont.damage.ratio <- exp(fixed[1]  +  fixed[2])
lwrCloth.damage.ratio <- exp(wald[1,1]) 
lwrCont.damage.ratio <- exp(wald[1,1] + wald[2,1]) 
uprCloth.damage.ratio <- exp(wald[1,2]) 
uprCont.damage.ratio <- exp(wald[1,2] + wald[2,2]) 

estCloth.damage <- estCloth.damage.ratio/ (1+estCloth.damage.ratio)
estCont.damage <- estCont.damage.ratio / (1+ estCont.damage.ratio)
lwrCloth.damage <- lwrCloth.damage.ratio/ (1+ lwrCloth.damage.ratio)
lwrCont.damage <- lwrCont.damage.ratio /(1+ lwrCont.damage.ratio)
uprCloth.damage <- uprCloth.damage.ratio /(1+uprCloth.damage.ratio)
uprCont.damage <- uprCont.damage.ratio /(1+uprCont.damage.ratio )

treat.damage <- data.frame(Treatment,Estimate,lwr,upr)
```

What still confuses me are the high estimates of beyond 94%, yet

```
sum(df.cocoons.white$diseased)/length(df.cocoons.white$diseased)
```

gives me less than 70%. Doesn't seem realistic. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is using a logit transformation.

The way I look at generalized linear models is that they really aren't any different than simple linear regression.  In simple linear regression, your response variable is continuous on (theoretically) the entire real number line (-Inf, Inf).

In logistic regression, your response is a proportion, which is continuous on the interval [0, 1].  The odds calculates (p / (1-p)) which is continuous over the interval of [0, inf).  The log odds `log(p / (1-p))` is continuous over the interval (-Inf, Inf).

This complete transformation (`log(p / (1-p))`) is referred to as the logit transformation and is pretty standard in logistic regression.

The results of your `glmer` model, which is a random effects version of logistic regression, uses the same transformation and so the estimated coefficients are on the scale of (-Inf, Inf).  If you want odds ratios, you can exponentiate the coefficients, which will give you the odds measured on a scale of (0, Inf), with 1.0 being the null value.

Comment: @ Benjamin: Thanks :-) . I tried to do this transformation before based on what I saw in this forum about lmer with `tmp <- as.data.frame(confint(glht(ABPV.prev.0))$confint) tmp$Estimate <- exp(tmp$Estimate) tmp$lwr <- exp(tmp$lwr) tmp$upr <- exp(tmp$upr).`However the results don't look reasonable to me with tmp being `tmp Estimate lwr upr pseudotreatmentC 1.801179e-05 2.586979e-10 1.254068 pseudotreatmentN 1.919081e-05 8.158977e-11 4.513892 `Any ideas why it is like that?